# How to create a Register User action in OData asp.net Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, odata

I am trying to implement a method for registering a user in my OData based asp.net Web API.
The ploblem is i would like to have it on the root url followed by /Register.

The register action itself makes use of a RegisterModel which contains the right information to create the user.

I have tried to add a custom action in the WebApiConfig. Problem with this is that OData then expects a simple parameter and sending whole models over won't succeed.

Simple action specification like below won't work for me. The endpoint can be found but the model is always 'null'.

```
var actionRegister = builder.Action("Register");
actionRegister.Parameter<RegisterModel>("model");
actionRegister.Returns<IdentityResult>();
```

The API method is started as follows:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost]
[ODataRoute("Register")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Register(RegisterModel model)
{
```

Any help is welcome. My ultimate goal would be to have a controller call in my user controller that can register users via the route /Register.

Comment: What is `RegisterModel`? Is it a structured type that can be found in the metadata document?

Comment: The `RegisterModel` is a model I use to put in all the data needed to register a user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a look at the http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/WebApi/OData/v4/ODataActionsSample/ODataActionsSample/ sample code here, the unbound function should meet your needs.

Comment: I don't know what I exactly did wrong but following the example works great! Thanks for helping out!